# checkbox not firing event after checked is set programmatically

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I am iterating through a string of characters and finding a checkbox. I find the checkbox without any problems and if the character of the iteration is equal to 't', I set the Checked property of the checkbox to true.

However, for whatever reason, although it does check the appropriate checkboxes, executing this code also means that when I click any checkbox myself, nothing happens (everything works just fine and I can check anything until I execute this code). Also, the submit button on my page no longer does anything if I execute this code. I'm puzzled as to what may be the reason for this.

The buttons are created programmatically on init and are located inside an update panel.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 11, 18);

foreach (char c in attendee.accommodation)
{
     ID = "accommodationCheckBox" + date.ToShortDateString();
     CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)FindControl(ID);
     if (checkbox != null && c == 't')
         {
             checkbox.Checked = true;
         }
     date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

Here is an example of how the checkbox looks like in the end: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzxo047o/

EDIT: Scenario: You fill in a dynamically generated form on A.aspx, then you see a "registration overview" on B.aspx. If you want to modify your registration at that point, you hit a button which creates a new instance of A.aspx and fills it with your registration data from database, which is what I'm solving right now. I dynamically create some checkboxes and based on a value of string, either check them or not. They get checked as they should, but I'm unable to manually control them / click them.

Comment: Try setting the `AutoPostBack` property of checkbox to true.

Comment: it does have it on true

Comment: Use Guid to append to the id or increment number and see if that works

Comment: I need to be able to reconstruct the ID of the given checkbox based on date to which it relates.

Comment: i m not sure but, could u bind checkbox in pageload again?

Answer (score 0):

```
checkbox.CheckedChanged += yourcheck_event;
```

If the checkbox is created dynamically, you have to add the event to it.

Comment: it does have a checkedchanged event hooked to it - as I was saying, it works just fine, but stops working when I execute the code above.

Comment: Could I maybe see an example of your frontend code? Do all the checkBox IDs have the date appended to them?

Comment: Sure. All the checkboxes have ID with the date appended to them. Here's an example of how the checkbox looks like in the end: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzxo047o/

Comment: Could it be that your code is unable to distinguish each check box due to more than one of them having the same ID?

Comment: no, all IDs are unique as they should be, I checked

Comment: does it update on the front end that the checkbox has been checked?
Maybe try a panel.Update() after you execute the code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your UpdatePanel has it's UpdateMode property set to "Always".

Take on count that:

> the UpdatePanel control’s content is only updated when one of the
>   following is true:
>
> When the postback is caused by a trigger for that UpdatePanel control.
>   When you explicitly call the UpdatePanel control's Update method. When
>   the UpdatePanel control is nested inside another UpdatePanel control
>   and the parent panel is updated.

…

Comment: Setting UpdateMode to always didn't help, but I think the note is on topic. The thing is: You fill in a dynamically generated font on A.aspx, then you see a "registration overview" on B.aspx. If you want to modify your registration at that point, you hit a button which creates a new instance of A.aspx and fills it with your registration data from database. I think this may have something to do with what the note above describes.

Comment: sorry, by font I meant form.